# Finding the remainder .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

How to find the remainder of $\dfrac{7^{8^9}}{1000}$

Comment: Hint: it's the same as $7^8 \mod 1000$ and the same as $7^{8^5} \mod 1000$. Why?

Answer (score 2):

1. $7^{20}$ gives the remainder $1$ when divided by $1000$.
2. $8^9$ and $8$ give the same remainder when divided by $20$.
3. Hence $7^{8^9}=7^{20k+8}=(7^{20})^k7^8$. Since $7^8=801$, so this is your answer.

Comment: And thus, we encourage yet another user to make no-effort PSQ's...

Comment: @Vadim123, how $7^{20}\equiv1\pmod{1000}?$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee not revealing a technique for proving that helps make this post not an encouragement for PSQs, but rather some guidance. `:)`  (at least, that's how I see it...)

Comment: @anorton, in contrast, all I see is *"so this is your answer."* ...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 And go ahead and try to turn "801" in as a homework answer `:)` --you may get a point or two for a correct response, but a teacher will want to see the work for it (typing into WolframAlpha can get you the answer, but not the process).  Giving a sketch as to how to proceed is very helpful, but it doesn't give away the entire problem,,.  But this should probably be discussed in chat or on meta if we want to talk about it further--I don't want to clutter the area under vadim's answer. `;)`